# How to determine the HTTP status without downloading the complete page?

Tags: command-line, wget, curl

I want to know the HTTP Status of the websites using Ubuntu. 
I have used `curl` and `wget` command for that purpose. But the problem is these commands download the complete website page and then search for the header and display it on the screen. 
For example:

```
$ curl -I trafficinviter.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 02 Jan 2017 14:13:14 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Pingback: http://trafficinviter.com/xmlrpc.php
Link: <http://trafficinviter.com/>; rel=shortlink
Set-Cookie: wpfront-notification-bar-landingpage=1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Same thing happens with `Wget`command where the complete page is getting downloaded and unnecessarily consuming my bandwidth.

What I am looking for is: how to get the HTTP status code without actually downloading any page so that I can save my bandwidth consumption. I had tried using curl but not sure is I am downloading complete page or just a header to my system to get the status code.

Comment: "tried using curl but not sure is I am downloading complete page or just a header" — `curl -v` (`--verbose`) option is a handy way to debug what curl is actually sending & receiving.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm downvoting because you already have the solution right there in the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was not knowing whether the question is my answer or not. I was here to have help to resolve my confusion. If you still find that my question is wrong.. I welcome your decision of downvote.. thank you

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/curl.1.html

Comment: "these commands download the complete website page" - no, they don't

Comment: @OrangeDog I got it from the answers. This was my confusion.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`curl -I` fetches *only* the HTTP headers; it does not download the whole page. From [`man curl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/curl.1.html):

```
-I, --head
      (HTTP/FTP/FILE) Fetch the HTTP-header only! HTTP-servers feature
      the command HEAD which this uses to get nothing but  the  header
      of  a  document. When used on an FTP or FILE file, curl displays
      the file size and last modification time only.
```

Another option is to install `lynx` and use `lynx -head -dump`.

The HEAD request is specified by the HTTP 1.1 protocol ([RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)):

```
9.4 HEAD

   The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
   return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
   to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can
   be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the
   request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is
   often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
   and recent modification.
```

Comment: is it possible (within the bounds of the standard.. obviously it's _possible_) for a HEAD request to return a different status code than a GET?

Comment: @KutuluMike: Edited the answer to provide the requested information. In the words of the RFC, it SHOULD provide the same metainformation.

Comment: @duskwuff: Then a HEAD request SHOULD return the same 405.

Comment: @AlexP My mistake. Never mind!

Answer (score 18):

With `wget`, [you need to use the `--spider` option](https://superuser.com/a/797372/334516) to send a HEAD request like curl:

```
$ wget -S --spider https://google.com
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-01-03 00:08:38--  https://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 216.58.197.174
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|216.58.197.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Cache-Control: private
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Location: https://www.google.co.jp/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=...
  Content-Length: 262
  Date: Mon, 02 Jan 2017 15:08:38 GMT
  Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"
Location: https://www.google.co.jp/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=... [following]
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-01-03 00:08:38--  https://www.google.co.jp/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=...
Resolving www.google.co.jp (www.google.co.jp)... 210.139.253.109, 210.139.253.93, 210.139.253.123, ...
Connecting to www.google.co.jp (www.google.co.jp)|210.139.253.109|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Mon, 02 Jan 2017 15:08:38 GMT
  Expires: -1
  Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=Shift_JIS
  P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
  Server: gws
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Set-Cookie: NID=...; expires=Tue, 04-Jul-2017 15:08:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.jp; HttpOnly
  Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Accept-Ranges: none
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
```

Comment: Don't you think my friend that wget will fetch the complete page and then display the header.

Comment: @JafferWilson read the last few lines of the output.